# How can i get this table from this website using google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I want to get some data from this web site in a google sheet I tried importhtml , importxml but nothing is working for me. Does any one can test if  is possible to get the data? How can I do that?

https://www.scorespro.com/livescore-opap/#

Or if not possible from this site what about this site

https://free.scorespro.com/opap-livescore/soccer.php

Comment: can you show us what you have tried and what errors you are encountering?

Comment: Yes, I tried =IMPORTHTML("https://www.scorespro.com/livescore-opap/";"table";1) but it says that the content is empty (#N/A)

Answer (score 1):

This website is generated by javascript and cannot be imported using Google Sheets formulas. You can check it using IMPORTDATA. Normally it pulls out all the contents. But not here.

Also it is a commercial website that provides live data through their API.
So it's quite normal that it is not easy to **scrape**.

#### Related:

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun)

Comment: I appreciate your help. Do you have any suggestion on how should I approach that? I mean what would you do if you wanted to get that table in a google sheet. They do have a free API but is only for web sites. What would you do?

Comment: It there's an API Get where you put the information you need (and authorisation key too) in url address then you can import it's contents into google sheets. The easiest way is when they provide data in xml format. Then you can use importxml to fetch the data you need from provided content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I send them an email to see if they can provide a free xml API for personal use. I hope I can procced further.

Comment: FYI ‘to scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish. The correct term for what you’re doing is __scrape__

Comment: Thanks :-) English is not my native language :-)